# disable scrollview childs but keep scrollable and enable appearance

Tags: android

I'm dealing with a problem, hope you can help me.

I want to disable all childs inside a scrollview, but i want to be able to scroll and also maintain the appearance of the views the same as if they where enabled.

My layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/newEventScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <com.xw.repo.BubbleSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/durationBubble"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"                    
                app:bsb_bubble_color="@color/colorPrimaryDarker"
                app:bsb_bubble_text_color="@color/colorWhite"
                app:bsb_max="12"
                app:bsb_min="0"
                app:bsb_progress="0"
                app:bsb_second_track_color="@color/colorPrimaryDarker"
                app:bsb_section_count="2"
                app:bsb_section_text_position="below_section_mark"
                app:bsb_show_progress_in_float="true"
                app:bsb_show_section_mark="true"
                app:bsb_show_section_text="true"
                app:bsb_show_thumb_text="false"
                app:bsb_thumb_radius="8dp"
                app:bsb_track_color="@color/colorWhite" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/hearingLoss" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/hearingLossSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:theme="@style/SCBSwitch" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What i need is to don't let the user to change any view, like switch or seekBar.
I've tried this things:

Disable nested views, scroll working but disable appearance that i dont like.

```
private void disableEnableControls(boolean enable, ViewGroup vg){
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(enable);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup){
            disableEnableControls(enable, (ViewGroup)child);
        }
    }
}
```

Do nothing on OnClickListener, scroll not working

```
private void disableEnableControls(boolean enable, ViewGroup vg){
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
        child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup){
            disableEnableControls(enable, (ViewGroup)child);
        }
    }
}
```

Create another view inside scrollview and setting visible when i want, scroll not working.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [mcve] perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a view (which I am assuming you are talking about views such as those with click listeners or checkboxes,...), you can simply disable the click listeners (if that is what you want) in your java code: either set an if condition in your listener callback method, or set the clickable feature of the view to false.

Comment: Doing that the scrollView is not scrollable anymore